# How to create office365 calender background Add-In

Tags: outlook-addin, office365api, office365-apps

We are working on office365 outlook Add-In, In which we need to perform some business logic as soon as any appointment is added/updated/deleted from outlook calendar. For that we need to handle the calendar event(Appointment Add/Update/Delete) same as VSTO Add-In, which is working in background i.e. it is not required any UI for user action. We need to create Add-In which is supporting Web, Desktop and mobile application for outlook.
   Please help us to create this Add-In.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) may be helpful in understanding